# Validation loop needed and Binary to Decimal not outputting the right answer

Tags: java, validation, loops, binary

I know this is ugly, but it works (not really) it just compiles successfully

I cannot use Integer.parseInt() or Math.max

i have to define each char and set up the algorithm to check

I understand the concept of an 8 digit binary number like 11111111 has a decimal of 255 however in my program it is like 12495...WHAT GIVES what am i doing wrong?

also not every binary number is 8 characters, how can i allow the code to accept that and validate that only 1's and 0's are inputted in the prompt?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Binary
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Binary Number Please:");
        String aString = keyboard.next();
        char aChar = aString.charAt(0);
        int digit_1 = aString.charAt(0);
        char bChar = aString.charAt(1);
        int digit_2 = aString.charAt(1);
        char cChar = aString.charAt(2);
        int digit_3 = aString.charAt(2);
        char dChar = aString.charAt(3);
        int digit_4 = aString.charAt(3);
        char eChar = aString.charAt(4);
        int digit_5 = aString.charAt(4);
        char fChar = aString.charAt(5);
        int digit_6 = aString.charAt(5);
        char gChar = aString.charAt(6);
        int digit_7 = aString.charAt(6);
        char hChar = aString.charAt(7);
        int digit_8 = aString.charAt(7);
        float dec_1 = (digit_1*128);
        float dec_2 = (digit_2*64);
        float dec_3 = (digit_3*32);
        float dec_4 = (digit_4*16);
        float dec_5 = (digit_5*8);
        float dec_6 = (digit_6*4);
        float dec_7 = (digit_7*2);
        float dec_8 = (digit_8*1);
        float Answer = (dec_1+dec_2+dec_3+dec_4+dec_5+dec_6+dec_7+dec_8);
        System.out.println(Answer);
    }//End bracket method main
}//End bracket class Binary
```

Comment: edited code to reflect fix from John Con

Comment: Should your program accept fewer than 8 or more than 8 binary digits, or both?

Comment: @Ole both truly

Comment: Please leave the question as a question—I rolled it back. (If you want, you can write your own answer. And even accept it when you decide it is the best answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go... should work - make sure you understand the code:
Took all of 5 minutes...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class binary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Binary Number Please:");
        String aString = keyboard.next();
        int sizeOf = aString.length();
        int[] binArray = new int[sizeOf];
        char digitBin = ' ';
        int digitChar = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeOf; i++){
            digitBin = aString.charAt(0);
            digitChar = Character.getNumericValue(digitBin);
            binArray[i] = digitChar;
        }
        int total = 0;
        int multiplyNum = 1;
        for(int i = sizeOf - 1; i > -1; i--){
            total = (binArray[i] * multiplyNum) + total;
            multiplyNum = multiplyNum * 2;
        }
        System.out.println(total);

    }

}
```

If you dont know Arrays that well and all of your loops - better start practicing... You will use them a ton in school!

Comment: I tested only one binary num and it was correct - make sure to test - might need some simple tweeking.

Answer (score 1):

Math is correct but when you are looking at charAt(position) it is returning a character and that should be given you the ASCII value and not the digit value.

You should be using something like this

```
Character.getNumericValue(c)
```

so something like this

```
char theChar0 = String.charAt(0);
int digit0 = Character.getNumericValue(theChar0);
```

I am pretty sure this is correct - I am a recent college grad so not an expert by any means but good luck!

Comment: That worked perfectly to get the right answer, Thank you! now to figure out why it will not do lesser than 8 digit binary and to put a validation loop in it

Answer (score 0):

The standard way would to use a loop over the characters entered. Each time through the loop, first check that current value is either 0 or 1 (if not, issue error message and break out), multiply what you already have by 2 and add value of current digit. For instance, if input os 101 (which should equal 5): Start with 0. For the first digit, 1 (which is either 0 or 1, so it’s fine), your loop will do 2 * 0 + 1 = 1. Second digit (0) gives 2 * 1 + 0 = 2. Last digit 2 * 2 + 1 = 5. You’re done.

This works for 1 through 31 binary digits if you are doing the calculations in type `int`.

For breaking out in case the value is not 0 or 1, you may throw an exception that you can catch in the right place.

Wonder why your research didn’t turn this up already. Surely it must be described in many places on the Internet. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could always use a

```
int numOfDig = String.length();
```

then place the numOfDig and create a for loop to enter the data into an array with array size also being the numOfDig

then another for loop to do the math.  Hope that makes sense.